# VBA: Remove duplicate cells based on id

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with multiple duplicates (Log in) for an id. I need to remove the duplicates until the last login, like in the example below.

I have the following table:

```
Id      Status     Date    
A      Log in      01.01.2018  01:44:03
A      Log out     01.01.2018  02:57:03
C      Log in      01.01.2018  01:55:03
C      Log in      01.01.2018  01:59:03
C      Log in      01.01.2018  01:59:03 
D      Log in      01.01.2018  01:59:03 
E      Log in      01.01.2018  01:59:03 
E      Log out     01.01.2018  01:59:03
```

The table should look like this:

```
Id      Status     Date    
A      Log in      01.01.2018  01:44:03
A      Log out     01.01.2018  02:57:03
E      Log in      01.01.2018  01:59:03 
E      Log out     01.01.2018  01:59:03
```

To do this, I tried to use the following code. The problem is that it will remove the duplicates, but the first login for an id will remain, not the last one. If I will start the "for" loop form the last cell to the first one it will be ok, but it is not possible (to remove the duplicates in opposite direction). Any idea how I can fix this? Thanks!
*ID D is removed because after Log In should be Log Out.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xCol As Long
    Dim x2Row As Long
    Dim x2Col As Long
    Dim xrg As Range
    Dim xrg2 As Range
    Dim xl As Long
    Dim x2 As Long

    Set xrg = Application.InputBox("Select a range:", "Kutools for Excel", _
                                    ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal, , , , , 8)    
    Set xrg2 = Application.InputBox("Select a range:", "Kutools for Excel", _
                                    ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal, , , , , 8)

    xRow = xrg.Rows.Count + xrg.Row - 1
    x2Row = xrg2.Rows.Count + xrg2.Row - 1
    xCol = xrg.Column
    x2Col = xrg2.Column
    'MsgBox xRow & ":" & xCol
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    For xl = xRow To 2 Step -1 
        If Cells(xl, xCol) = Cells(xl - 1, xCol) Then
            If Cells(xl, x2Col) = Cells(xl - 1, x2Col) Then
                Cells(xl, xCol) = ""
                Cells(xl, x2Col) = ""                
            End If
        End If
    Next xl
```

Comment: Please explain why id **D** should be removed...............it is not duplicated in the original list.

Comment: Because after Log in should be a Log out (I forgot to explain). After Log in should be always a Log out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In column E use the formula

```
=IF(B2="Log in",IF(AND(A2=A3,B3="log out"),"valid","delete"),"valid")
```

in E2 and pull down. Then filter by `valid` or loop through column E and throw out all having `delete`.

[image]

---

#### Extended version

Note that this method doesn't cover the possibility that another Id `X` loggs in and out inbeween Id `A` for example:

[image]

In this case the test would be more complicated:

While the first validation method fails here the extended recognizes these cases.

- Column F: `=A:A&B:B`
- Column G (and pull down)

  ```
    =IF(F2=A2&"Log in",IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2&"Log out",F3:$F$1048576,0)>0,"valid"),"delete"),"valid")
  ```

[image]

Comment: @CatalinVasilescu See the extended version if this case can happen to you. This might be the better solution.

Comment: theoretically should not happen because I sorted the id but thanks!

Comment: @CatalinVasilescu Yes, that's probably the better option: Sorting by `Id`, `Date`, `Time` (in this order) and use formula 1.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the solution you are asking for, but there is an easier way:
Create a pivot table
Add ID and Status as Row fields
Put the Date as value, set to show maximum

You might have to format the dates as dates as well

Answer (score 0):

try with below

Assuming your data starts with A2 (please see the image below)

In D2 apply the below formula and drag down up to D9

=IF(OR(AND(A2=A3,B2="Log in",B3="Log out"),AND(A2=A1,B2="Log Out",B1="Log in")),"Keep","Delete")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
Sub test()

    Dim ID As String, Status As String, strDate As String
    Dim LastrowA As Long, LastrowE As Long, i As Long
    Dim cell As Range, rngToSearch As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")

        LastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastrowA

            ID = .Range("A" & i).Value
            Status = .Range("B" & i).Value
            strDate = .Range("C" & i).Value

            If Status = "Log in" Then

                Set rngToSearch = .Range("A" & i + 1)

                For Each cell In rngToSearch

                    If cell.Value = ID And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> Status Then

                        LastrowE = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

                        .Range("E" & LastrowE + 1).Value = ID
                        .Range("F" & LastrowE + 1).Value = Status
                        .Range("G" & LastrowE + 1).Value = strDate
                        .Range("E" & LastrowE + 2).Value = cell.Value
                        .Range("F" & LastrowE + 2).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                        .Range("G" & LastrowE + 2).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value

                    End If

                Next

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear that my answer helps. if any of the posted answers helps you or is the actual answer just void to helps others with the some problem.